# Using Airflow DAG run conf in BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator

Tags: python, airflow, apache-beam, dataflow, data-processing

### **Background**

I am trying to run an Apache Beam pipeline as part of an Airflow DAG. The DAG run is triggered manually with a `user_id` parameter. Typically, in my `PythonOperator` I can access my DAG run `conf` as part of the arguments to the `python_callable`. For example:

```
def python_operator_example(ds, conf, dag_run):
    # Can easily access my user_id parameter
    user_id = dag_run.conf['user_id']
```

### **Problem**

Now, I have created a `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` in which I want to access the `user_id` as well.

```
process_data = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="process_data",
    pipeline_options={
        "input": "/Users/myuser/Desktop/test.txt",
        "output": "/Users/myuser/Desktop/foo/"
    },
    py_file='pipeline/process_data.py'
)
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to access the DAG run `conf` within the `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`. There seems to be no way to pass inputs from  `dag_run.conf` to a Beam pipeline at runtime. Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
## 1. Define a function to set pipeline inputs dynamically using dag_run

def create_beam_pipeline_options(ds, conf, dag_run):
    return {
        "user_id": dag_run.conf['user_id'],
        "input": "/Users/myuser/Desktop/test.txt",
        "output": "/Users/myuser/Desktop/foo/"
    }

## 2. Pass the function into operator to generate options when pipeline task is invoked

process_data = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="process_data",
    pipeline_options=create_beam_pipeline_options,
    py_file='pipeline/process_data.py'
)
```

### **Question**

What is the correct way to pass values like `dag_run.conf` that are defined at runtime as pipeline options into the `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`?

**What I have already tried**

- I checked whether `argv` in the pipleline's `run` function contains `dag_run.conf` but it does not.
- I looked into whether I could use XCom to pass data from a pervious DAG task using `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` but didn't find anything.
- I explored some solutions that allow me to dynamically create a new DAG for each `user_id` but that seems wasteful and anti-pattern.
- I read the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-beam/stable/operators.html) and [code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/apache/beam/operators/beam.py) for suggestions

My sincere apologies in advance if this is a silly question, I am quite new to using Beam / Airflow!

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using a `PythonOperator` that calls a `BeamHook`. It looks something like this.

```
from airflow.providers.apache.beam.operators.beam import (
    BeamHook,
    BeamRunnerType
)

beam_hook = BeamHook(BeamRunnerType.DirectRunner)

def process_data(ds, conf, dag_run):
    beam_hook.start_python_pipeline(
        variables={"user_id": dag_run.conf["user_id"]},
        py_file='dags/pipeline/pipline/process_data.py',
        py_options=[],
        py_requirements=['apache-beam'],
        py_interpreter='python3',
        py_system_site_packages=False,
    )
```